# When I try to re-enable a constraint in SQL Server, I get "ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with COLUMN FOREIGN KEY constraint"

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I need to update few records in tables of a database. There are few foreign key constraints on these tables.

To disable constraint, I am using this:-

```
ALTER TABLE Table_01 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL 
ALTER TABLE Table_02 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL 
ALTER TABLE Table_01 DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

To Enable constraint back, I am using this:-

```
ALTER TABLE Table_01 ENABLE TRIGGER ALL 
ALTER TABLE Table_01 WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL 
ALTER TABLE Table_02 WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

But for some reasons, when i try to put constraint back, it gives this error:-

```
ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with COLUMN FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Table_01_AAAAA_AAAA'. 
The conflict occurred in database 'DB', table 'Table_02', column 'ID'.
```

Note: I have many locations where similar database is installed. so this enabled / disable constraint is working on some database but not all.

Answer (score 5):

One of the updates you performed violated the foreign key constraint. You won't be able to enable it again until you find and correct the offending data.